# How to download YouTube video subtitles in English using youtube-dl?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-dl, video-subtitles

I have tried to download subtitles along with the video using the following Python 3.x code. It's just not working.

Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
ydl_opts = {
'outtmpl': '/PATH/%(title)s'+'.mp4',
'format':' (bestvideo[width>=?1080]/bestvideo)+bestaudio/best',
'subtitle': '--write-srt --sub-lang en',
}
url = input("Enter your URL: ")
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
print("Downloaded!")
```

Comment: The --write-srt option is for downloading subtitles uploaded by owner, if the video doesn't have any subtitles uploaded by owner it may not work. Try --write-auto-sub.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `'writesubtitles': True` for youtube-dl to download subtitles. Also, you should specify `[ext=mp4]` or the program may download .webm files which are incompatible with mp4 format. The following code solves these problems:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
ydl_opts = {
'outtmpl': '/Downloads/%(title)s_%(ext)s.mp4',
'format': '(bestvideo[width>=1080][ext=mp4]/bestvideo)+bestaudio/best',
'writesubtitles': True,
'subtitle': '--write-sub --sub-lang en',
}
url = input("Enter your URL: ")
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
print("Download Successful!")
```

Also, make sure to keep `ffmpeg.exe` in your youtube-dl folder for merging video and audio files. You can get it [from here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).